# Chipmunk body move with Parallax?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, collision, chipmunk

I'm using Cocos2D, SpaceManager and Chipmunk.  I have a parallax node with 4 layers on it, this is tied to the location of a playable chipmunk body.  This body needs to collide with static objects on one of the parallax layers, the static bodies must start off screen then move into screen and collide.

I know you are not supposed to move static bodies with Chipmunk, unless you rehash.  However, rehashing 60 time a second to keep up with the framerate seems messy.  Can anyone think of an alternate way to do this?

Cheers.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is joining all the objects in each parallax layer to a non-colliding body using rigid joints. Then move that body along with the parallax layer to drag the objects along. THis may not be the best method, though.

Comment: Hello.  Thanks for the reply.  In the end I worked out how to use my main dynamic body to move the parallax node, once I've tidied I'll be posting my code in case it helps others.